# Change Facebook "Watching" activity to "Watched"

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, status

When adding a status update with the Watching activity, the status posts to my timeline as "*Hashim is watching Kong*".

Is there a way to change this to something like:

> *Hashim watched Kong*

...or...

> *Hashim was watching Kong*

Anything to indicate that I watched the movie early on in the day rather than at the moment I updated the status?

I recall that a few months ago there was an option to change the exact time that an activity occurred, but I can no longer find it.

**Update in response to Phong's answer (26/03/17)**

This is the problem; the option pictured in his answer no longer exists for me at all, despite the fact it did maybe 6 months ago. Also, my interface hasn't looked like that in a while. @Phong - are all your screenshots recent? This is what mine currently looks like:

[image]

And when the status panel is clicked on:

[image]

I'm aware that Facebook likes to experiment with making certain features available to certain geographies - which might be an explanation for why I'm missing the Change Date feature - but I didn't think that applied to entire aspects of the UI. I'm from the North of the UK, for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the date of a post (at least one featuring an activity) no longer appears to be possible via the **Facebook app** (v.85 for iOS) or the **mobile website** as of March 24th, 2017.

However you can still make that change using the **full Facebook website**, which can be forced on a phone by navigating to https://www.facebook.com/home.php. It has to be entered exactly; otherwise you’ll be redirected to the mobile site.

When posting such an activity, click the rightmost option seen below:

[image: New Activity Post]

That post may be edited after the fact by clicking the downward arrow next to your post <kbd>v</kbd>:

[image: Editing Post]

In my testing, changing the date of the activity post by just a few minutes updated *is watching* to *was watching*.

Comment: Can you please attached the SS for _watched_, because in my testing changing the date doesn't change it from watching to watched. Changing the date will change from your post flow from Timeline, means if you post something today and if you change the date, it will show in that order.